# How to handle asset/chunk naming in a standard fashion when Building a multipage app with Vite 4 using Vue 3?

Tags: asp.net-core, vuejs3, vite, rollupjs

I am using Vite 4.1.4/Vue 3.2.45 and trying to build a [Multipage App](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#multi-page-app) (not in lib mode) to be served by an ASP.NET Core website (using Razor pages (cshtml)) as the entry points.

I am trying to build each page/entry point as a self contained folder with all js and css inside, even duplicating modules if needs be.

I have the following directory structure in the `src` folder:

```
├───assets
│      /*Asserts here*/
├───components
│       /*components here*/
├───composables
│       /*composables here*/
├───pages
│   │   ErrorNotFound.vue
|   |   /* Pages here */
│   ├───Propertylistings
│   │       propertylistings.ts
│   │       PropertyListings.vue
│   ├───Tasks
│   │       tasks.ts
│   │       Tasks.vue
│   │       TasksDetail.vue
│   │       TasksGrid.vue
│   └───Users
│           users.ts
│           Users.vue
│           UsersDetail.vue
│           UsersGrid.vue
├───router
│       taskRouter.ts
│       userRouter.ts
|       /* Others here*/
├───services
│   │   Services.ts
│   └───api
│           Api.ts
└───viewmodels
        TaskDTO.ts
        UserDTO.ts
        /* etc */
```

My vite config looks as below:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'url'
import glob from 'glob';
import path from 'node:path';

var inputFiles = (glob.globSync('src/pages/**/*.ts')).map(file => [
  // This remove `src/` as well as the file extension from each
  // file, so e.g. src/nested/foo.js becomes nested/foo
  path.relative(
    'src',
    file.slice(0, file.length - path.extname(file).length)
  ),
  // This expands the relative paths to absolute paths, so e.g.
  // src/nested/foo becomes /project/src/nested/foo.js
  fileURLToPath(new URL(file, import.meta.url))
]);

const outputDir = "../wwwroot/client";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue()
  ],
  build: {
    outDir: outputDir,
    emptyOutDir: true,
    manifest: "manifest.json",
    sourcemap: true,
    cssCodeSplit: false, /* 1 style file */
    rollupOptions: {
      input: Object.fromEntries(inputFiles),
      output: {
        format: "es",
        sourcemap: true,
        exports: 'named',
        assetFileNames: (assetInfo) => {
          console.log("AssertInfo %s, %s", assetInfo.name, assetInfo.type)
          let extType = assetInfo.name.split('.').pop();
          if (/png|jpe?g|svg|gif|tiff|bmp|ico/i.test(extType)) {
            extType = 'img';
          }
          return `assets/[name]-[hash][extname]`;
        },
      },
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  server: {
    /*Proxy settings for dev */
  }
})
```

This produces the following output in the `outDir`:

```
│   manifest.json
│
└───assets
    │   BusyButton-e579a0b5.js /* This name seems chosen at random */
    │   BusyButton-e579a0b5.js.map
    │   ErrorNotFound-a6c93dbd.js
    │   ErrorNotFound-a6c93dbd.js.map
    │   style-341893d8.css /* How can I change this to be split per page? And named correctly? */
    │   _plugin-vue_export-helper-175348a6.js
    │   _plugin-vue_export-helper-175348a6.js.map
    │
    └───pages
        ├───Propertylistings
        │       propertylistings-4859e993.js
        │       propertylistings-4859e993.js.map
        │
        ├───Tasks
        │       tasks-a58b1702.js
        │       tasks-a58b1702.js.map
        │
        └───Users
                users-0e4c54f0.js
                users-0e4c54f0.js.map
```

`BusyButton` is one of the components I have created, and is used by a number of controls, I have no idea why it serves as the primary name for the bulk of the code. (it is the largest file)

If I remove the `cssCodeSplit` option then the `style-341893d8.css` file becomes `BusyButton-341893d8.css`.

Ideally I would like the css to be scoped and split per page (which will match the input array). If I can't have that I would like to pre-specify the name of the main css output bundle so that it does not change based on the output module that Vite generates (in this case `BusyButton`)

ie this structure:

```
    └───pages
        ├───Propertylistings
        |       propertylistings-4859e993.css /* Css file per page input */
        │       propertylistings-4859e993.js
        │       propertylistings-4859e993.js.map
        │
        ├───Tasks
        |       tasks-a58b1702.css /* Css file per page input */
        │       tasks-a58b1702.js
        │       tasks-a58b1702.js.map
        │
        └───Users
                users-0e4c54f0.css /* Css file per page input */
                users-0e4c54f0.js
                users-0e4c54f0.js.map
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you remove the `cssCodeSplit` option, this means setting `cssCodeSplit=true`. When enabled, CSS imported in async chunks will be inlined into the async chunk itself and inserted when the chunk is loaded. I'm guessing that the passing of the name might have something to do with the async chunk itself. This link may help you: [feat: align default chunk and asset file names with rollup](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/pull/10927).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am in the same situation, I have an asp.net core project with razor views. I am not even sure how to reference the js scripts & css files in the cshtml files since they have a hash code. I find it crazy that you cannot have full control over the destination of the files associated with each page. Ideally I would have liked the tool to modify the cshtml file directly.

Comment: @boggy, no sorry I have not figured it out. However to setup the Razor views, I used these posts from Shaun Wildermuth.
https://wildermuth.com/2023/01/18/vite-in-asp-net-core-projects/
https://www.codemag.com/Article/2109071/Introducing-Vite-A-Better-Vue-CLI

The setup for the Razor pages is quite simple if you follow his technique.